# get results from multiple tables using union or left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `booking` table with `booking_id`,`booking_type` columns. this table links with `booking_taxi` and `booking_bus` tables with foreign key `booking_id`.

`booking` :-
`booking_id | booking_type`

`booking_taxi` :-
`booking_taxi_id | booking_id | booking_date`

`booking_bus` :-
`booking_vus_id | booking_id | booking_date`

I came up with two queries to get all the bookings with the respective booking date.

query 1:

```
select  bk.booking_id,
        bk.booking_type,
        case
          when booking_type = 3 then bbus.booking_date
          when booking_type = 2 then btaxi.pickup_date
        end as booking_date
    from booking bk
left join booking_taxi btaxi on btaxi.booking_id = bk.booking_id and bk.booking_type = 2
left join booking_bus bbus on bbus.booking_id = bk.booking_id and bk.booking_type = 3;
```

query 2:

```
select  bk.booking_id,
        bk.booking_type,
        btaxi.booking_date
from booking bk
inner join booking_taxi btaxi on btaxi.booking_id = bk.booking_id and bk.booking_type = 2
union all
select  bk.booking_id,
        bk.booking_type,
        bbus.booking_date
from booking bk
inner join booking_bus bbus on bbus.booking_id = bk.booking_id and bk.booking_type = 3;
```

which one will have the better performance?.

Comment: Run `explain..` on these two queries, you will get the idea. Also, just run these queries with `sql_no_cache` flag, you can compare the performance yourself. My guess would be that the second one will be more performant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like query with Union All is faster than the Query with Left joins (at least for this scenario).

Left join query runs full scan three times (with nested loops)

[image: Explain Left Join]

But using Union all there are only two table scans

[image: Explain Union All]

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to know about relative performance, then you should run the queries to see which perform better on *your* data on *your* system.  You can garner information from `explain`.

Second, the queries are not identical.  They may *happen* to produce the same result set on your data.  But they are not guaranteed to.  In particular, the second removes duplicate values (because of the `union`) and the first does not.

Without any other information, I would expect the first to have better performance, specifically because the second incurs overhead for removing duplicate values.  However, that would need to be tested.

Also, the first will return booking values that are not `1` or `2`.  (I am assuming the 2/3 in the `FROM` clause is a typo.)

Personally, I prefer the first, although I am inclined to write it as:

```
select bk.booking_id, bk.booking_type,
       coalesce(btrain.booking_date, btaxi.pickup_date) as booking_date
from booking bk left join
     booking_taxi btaxi
     on btaxi.booking_id = bk.booking_id and
        bk.booking_type = 1 left join
        booking_bus bbus
     on bbus.booking_id = bk.booking_id and
        bk.booking_type = 2 and
        btaxi.booking_id is null
where btaxi.booking_id is not null or
      bbus.booking_id is not null;
```

There are three differences:

- `coalesce()` instead of `case`.  This is just shorter and easier to read.
- The condition `btaxi.booking_id is null` so the second `join` filters out rows where the first matches (this is actually redundant because the filter on `booking_type` does the same thing).
- The `where` condition to only return matches.

Answer (score 1):

Nested join is a join that compares every record in one table against every record in the other. If there are M in one table and N in second Table the complexity becomes MxN.

Based on that theory your second query using union will be more efficient

Comment: The DBMS uses indexes where available and appropriate. In a join it doesn't usually read a whole table to find a row, it uses the index tree and finds the row almost immediately. In both queries the DBMS is required to look up booking_taxi only on booking_type = 2. Once we add `where bk.booking_type in (2,3)` to the first query, we are asking for exactly the same data and the DBMS may see this and even come up with the same execution plan for both queries. (Admittedly, I don't find this likely with MySQL, but it would be possible.)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is: Is the datamodel appropriate? Are bus and taxi bookings so very different from each other? Does one booking really consist of multiple bookings of one vehicle type on different dates?

This

- booking : booking_id | booking_date | vehicle_id | trip_date
- vehicle : vehicle_id | vehicle_type | id_company | ...

for instance may or may not be more appropriate. Querying the data will become much easier, if you find a more appropriate datamodel.

As to your current datamodel and query:

- The query indicates that your datamodel allows inconsistencies. You can have a booking of type 2 but any of bbus, btaxi, btrain rows associated with it. You should find a way to change your datamodel so this cannot occur.
- The queries return different results as long as there can be other booking types or you don't add a where clause to the first query limiting booking rows to the required types.
- Both queries are fine. I think the second reads a little better. (It should be `UNION ALL` of course not `UNION [DISTINCT]`.)

As is, here is how I'd write the `UNION ALL` query:

```
select booking_id, 2 as booking_type, booking_date from btaxi
union all
select booking_id, 3 as booking_type, booking_date from btrain
order by booking_id, booking_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see queryplan in sqlserver and compaire performance of your queries .

however when you use join, if your tables are ordered with index sql compare them with nested join so when you create your tables with primarykey and forigenkey join has good performance ofcours you can make better performance with some index but in union sqlengine first get first query's result and sort it after that get second query result and sort that and compaire results and remove duplicate data so absolutly join is better than union .